# A model in DJANGO with 4 fields, two of them give error:"add a non-nullable field....". my question is why other two fields dont give error

Tags: mysql, django, migration

here is the full error:

You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'summary' to product without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows). Please select a fix: 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows) 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

My first question is why not all fields give me the error even tough they are identical fields?

Second question how can I fix this without typing this: TextField(default="any string") ?

Third question, I am using mysql,If I was using a different db would I get the same error?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    title=models.TextField()
    description=models.TextField()
    price=models.TextField()
    summary=models.TextField()
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

admin.site.register(Product)
```

**command**

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

my admin page has "Product" tab. When I create a product in admin window, i have only two fields. description and price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, I think there are existing rows in your db. When you want to add new columns on the existing table and you did not say the column is nullable by

```
summary=models.TextField(null=True)
```

So you have to set default value either during migration or you can define the default value in your model. You can choose `Option 1` during `makemigrations` and set `'Something' or None` as default.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer in the error:  `the database needs something to populate existing rows`.

It means that when you initially added first when you created a model and a first migration for it there were no any rows of instances.  But now you are trying to add another field separately to existing database and Django asks you to specify the default value for those existing rows.

There is a way to solve that issue:

Delete migrations where you crate that table and generate a new migration where all those fields will be credited simultaneously.

Comment: it didnt ask for first migration "title". It asked for the second one "description" but  it did not ask for the third one "price" and then asked for 4th one again. If i am not mistaken, based on what u said, only first migration should run through but rest doesnt. I wonder why 3rd one passed. how can i solve without adding a default value inside the field.

Comment: Migration is not a field. Migration is a special script that is stored in `migration` folder and is generated automatically when you call `./manage.py makemigrations`. It doesn't asks default value for those fields that were created in first initial migration when you created a database.

Comment: Sergey, I tried to create a new app called Movies, following same procedure, nothing is created :(. `python manage.py makemigrations`  running migrations:no migrations to apply :(

Comment: No need to create a new app. Delete all migrations in migration folder of the app you are changing model.